# Compile C#.net dll for VB6

Tags: c#, dll, vb6

I create a simple class like the one below:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace Seed
{
    class Plant
    {
       public string Planting () 
       {
        ....
       }
    }
 }
```

Can I call this function from VB6 code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, if you [expose your DLL as a COM component](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/COM/nettocom.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, but I did not use any interface. I think it is still able to execute? Some reference : http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;817248

Comment: Yes, you can follow that tutorial.

Comment: Side question: I use Regasm AssemblyName.dll /tlb: FileName.tlb /codebase to register the dll, how to register it again or remove the dll?

Comment: Please post a new question (so others can benefit when looking for the answer in search engines).