# Migrate Vb to Vb.net (shared classes)

Tags: .net, wpf, vb.net, vb6

I have a question about the migration from vb6 to vb net. I must update a company software from vb6 to vb net. I want to know if is possible to create a class in wpf, using "Visual Studio 2010", that contain a structure and if this class can be used by old software written in vb6 ?

Thanks.

Nicola

Comment: I doubt it. .NET languages are compiled to CLR and not native machine instructions which makes the the binaries rather different. VB6 does not use this technology. While there may be a way (I'm often surprised ;-)) I very much doubt it.

Comment: Yes, use COM interop. Create a COM-visible class in your VB.Net

Comment: For instance see the answers to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934866/compile-c-net-dll-for-vb6

Comment: Neat @MarkJ, there seems to always be some way ;-)