# Can taglib-sharp be called from Visual Basic 6?

Tags: vb6, taglib-sharp

I still use Visual Basic 6 (VB6) for random personal coding and I need to read and write some FLAC tags (meta tags for music files) and if I knew how to access the library I would be able to code it quickly in VB6 where I would have to learn VB dot net from scratch.   Is there a shortcut to calling and using taglib-sharp from VB6 and does anyone have any examples?   Since I am only skilled in basic programming, please if you have something to share be as explicit as possible and don't assume I automatically know everything about it.   I do know how to add a DLL but I'd like to know if there is any way to call taglib sharp and how?   Thank you!!!  (VB6 is the only language I know and again this is for home use.)

Comment: I tried to register the DLL with this command:REGSVR32 C:\Windows\System32\taglib-sharp.dll ... and received the message taglib-sharp.dll was loaded but the entry-point DIRegisterServer was not found

Comment: You can edit your question to add more details, you don't have to do it as comments.

Comment: .NET DLLs are not COM-compatible by default. So you can't directly register them and use them in VB6

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compile C#.net dll for VB6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6934866/compile-c-net-dll-for-vb6)

Comment: Compiling C# is beyond my skill-level.   I was hoping to be able to do some coding in visual basic 6 to call the dll a special way and have it work.

Comment: Have you considered alternatives to that C# DLL, e.g. writing a UI for this [FLAC CLI too](https://xiph.org/flac/documentation_tools_flac.html) or using another library like [this one](https://www.un4seen.com/) which includes VB6 samples and is free for personal use.

Comment: IIRC Windows PowerShell is .NET enabled. Maybe you can call PowerShell from VB to call .NET classes