# How to get and set a vb6 property with parameter from c#?

Tags: c#, vb6

I need to get and set a property with parameter from a vb6 object:

```
Property Prop(ByVal type As SomeEnum) As Currency
```

This is how I create an instance of the object:

```
dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID(progID));
```

I tried the vb6 syntax in c#, but it doesn't work (doesn't even compile):

```
obj.Prop(enumValue) = 1.2m;
```

So the question is: How to get and set a vb6 property with parameter from c#?

**Edit:**

This method doesn't work with `dynamic`. AFAIK it works with COM Interop:

```
obj.get_Prop(enumValue);
obj.set_Prop(enumValue, newValue);
```

The reflection approach works fine, but it is too verbose:

```
obj.GetType().InvokeMember("Prop", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public |
    System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, obj,
    new object[] { enumValue, 1.2m });
```

The property indexer approach works too:

```
obj.Prop[enumValue] = 1.2m;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920512/help-call-c-sharp-winforms-dll-from-vb6-project

Comment: This has nothing to do with my question.

Comment: Good question (+1). I'm interested to see whether there's a good answer. One possibility would be to create a VB.Net component that wraps the VB6 and exposes it to C#. AFAICR VB.Net also supports properties with parameters, so VB.Net should be able to interact with the VB6. But it seems pretty excessive. I hope there's a better way (something using the reflection API?).

Comment: Ummm, in C# property indexers are writen like arrays. Did you try `obj.Prop[enumValue] = 1.2m;`?

Comment: The non-dynamic approach works fine: `obj.GetType().InvokeMember("Prop", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.SetProperty, null, obj, new object[] { enumValue, 1.2m });`. Don't have C# 4.0 installed at the moment, so can't play with `dynamic`.

Comment: Ok, I installed C# 4 on this machine out of curiosity. @tcarvin is correct, that syntax works. So tcarvin, feel free to post an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C# property indexers are writen like arrays.

```
obj.Prop[enumValue] = 1.2m;
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure on this, but I believe the Properties in VB6 COM Objects are actually translated to Methods in C#.

So a Property Get would be obj.get_Prop(); and a Property Set would be obj.set_Prop(newValue);