# Trying to call a C# COM object from VB 6

Tags: c#, vb6

I am trying to call a C# COM object from VB 6 and I am getting an  error:453 stating that it is hard to find the entrypoint to DLL.
I made all the modules in c# as public and my COM visibility to TRUE and I registerd my .dll file and I have Type library file available and I also invoke the P/Invoke call. Still I am getting the error. I am pasting my code below

VB6:

```
Private Declare Function DisplayCForm Lib "C:\Users\LP027077\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\COMWorld\COMWorld\bin\Debug\COMWorld.dll" ()
Private Sub Command1_Click()
DisplayCForm
End Sub
```

C#:

```
 namespace COMWorld
{

    [Guid("23047247-38D3-464F-A845-0D42A7ACD622")]
    [ComVisible(true)]
    public class COMObject
    {
        [DllImport("Kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "GetConsoleWindow",SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();
        public void COMModule()
        {
            Form f1 = new Form();
            f1.Text = "Hello VB6 from c# .NET";
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me in this regard!!
Thanks in advance

Comment: If I am reading this correctly, you are calling a method named `DisplayCForm` from your VB code but I do not see where that method is defined in your DLL...

Comment: Have you checked out this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920512/help-call-c-sharp-winforms-dll-from-vb6-project

Comment: I think you have to set the 'Alias' of your function, but it is a long time ago since I used VB 6 last

Comment: I am novice and trying it for the first time. So are both the functions should have name? since DisplayCForm is the user defined function?

Comment: I checked and made all the appropriate changes required for that @Christian47

Comment: Also, have you tried to add the 'static' attribute to your COMObject class?

Comment: When I tried to declare it as static I am getting an error that I can not declare instance members in a static class

Comment: I am not able to understand what the exact problem is with either my VB code or my C# code? can any one suggest me how to debug that?

Comment: Use CreateObject() to use a [ComVisible] class.

Comment: Is CreateObject() in Kernel32.dll? @Hans Passant

Comment: Is there any compatibility of 32 bit and 64 bit issues since my visual studio is 64 bit and VB6 is in 32 bit?

Comment: Now when I add CreateObject() I am getting error:424 Object Required My code is as follows

Comment: [VB:Set obj1 = CreateObject(COMWorld.COMObject)
Call obj1.DisplayCForm] @Hans Passant

Comment: @user1922454 - As long as you haven't compiled your DLL for 64-bit only, your 64-bit Visual Studio shouldn't cause a problem, because all VB6 programs are 32-bit.

Comment: @user1922454 - `CreateObject` takes a `String` argument: `Set obj1 = CreateObject("COMWorld.COMObject")`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I need to invoke a method on a .Net COM object from VB 6 code I usually do the following:

1. Add the COMVisible attribute to my .Net class and assembly.
2. Build and register my .Net assembly.
3. Add a reference to my .Net assembly in my VB project through the Project | References menu.
4. Use the "New" keyword in my VB code to create an instance of my .Net class using its progid and use that to invoke the required method.

The progid for your .Net assembly defaults to the assembly name plus the name of your class separated by a period. Once you have added a reference to your assembly in VB it should appear in both Intellisense and the Object Browser in the VB IDE.

To use your example with an assembly name of "COMWorld" and a class called "COMObject" and a method called "COMModule", my VB code would look like the following:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()

    Dim class1 As New COMWorld.COMObject
    class1.COMModule

End Sub
```

*Disclaimer: I'm afraid that I don't have the VB 6 IDE on my MacBook Air so the code might not be 100% compiler proof!*

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Chris! I did everything you specified and it helps me in getting new things. Now I am getting an error that Object doesn't support this property or method..! @Chris Neave

Comment: @user1922454 Remove the Declare statement in your code and use the COM object reference that Chris had you add to the project.

Answer (score 0):

Your "Declare Function" is used for "classic DLL", not COM.  With COM, just set a reference to it and then declare your object in the usual "Dim myObject as theCOMClass" syntax.

It's "hard to find" the entry point for the dll because the dll is a COM dll and you're trying to access it using header files instead of via the iUnknown interface.